# Space between icons in navbar

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the padding between the icons, but having a hard time positioning at flex-start. I've tried removing padding and margins but doesn't seem to work. I want the icons to be closer together.

I want to build it using flexbox but while I can add the icons I can't seem to work with the space in between each icon.

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/tylerisfatal/pen/bGgWpYY

```css
    .main-nav{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        background-color: #00008b;
    }
    
    .main-nav .main-nav-list{
        display: flex;
    
    }
    
    .main-nav .main-nav-list img {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 8%;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav role="navigation" class="main-nav">
            <ul class="main-nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#facebook">
                        <div>
                            <img src="img/facebook.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#yelp">
                        <div>
                            <img src="img/yelp.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#linkedin">
                        <div>
                            <img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please put together a [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tylerisfatal/pen/bGgWpYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you've set the `img` element to be 8% of the width of its parent. That parent is not the nav bar. The result is that the image is only occupying a small area of the list item, and forcing a lot of extra space beside. You also don't need the image inside a `div`, or the extra flex display properties on the image. Remove all that.

In general, you should have a rule that sets images to be a maximum of 100% of their containing element width, like this:

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Once you have that in place, you can just set the width on the parent element and remove the image width:

```css
nav li {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  width: 2rem;
}
```

Keeps your code more logical and avoids having rules that are unnecessarily many elements deep.

You'll also want to remove the bullet points created by using the `ul` and `li` elements:

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

[Here's an example of this using your code](https://codepen.io/tjnz/pen/VwPbKwB).

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for the elaborate answer. I am getting back in to CSS after a small break (burn out) and needed some more clarity!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:)

```
.main-nav{
    background-color: #00008b;
}

.main-nav .main-nav-list{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.main-nav .main-nav-list img {
    width: 8%;
}
```

Comment: So I can get that,  but there is space in between the icons. I want to push them closer together.